# passing null value in PreparedStatement setObject method gives exception

Tags: java, null, prepared-statement

Do we have a solution for this?

my code is something like this:

```
preparedStatement.SetObject(i , MyArray);
```

Here , MyArray is an array of record fetched form a table. Now , whenever the above statement finds a value null it throws an SQL exception : invalid Column type.

Options available are to use setObject(int parameterIndex, Object x, int sqlType) or setNull , but in that case i need to provide SQL type of the target column, which doesn't seem possible.

Thanks

Comment: "*i need to provide SQL type of the target column, which doesn't seem possible*". Why? Don't you know the definition of your table? (Btw: there is no `SetObject()` function in JDBC, only `setObject()`)

Answer (score 5):

you can try using setNull with NULL type:

```
if(myArray == null) {
    preparedStatement.setNull(i, Types.NULL);
}
```

And please follow Java coding standards - **variables and methods are initial lower case!**

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
preparedStatement.setObject(i , MyArray, java.sql.Types.ARRAY);
```

With the info available this is all I can come up with. Hopefully, this should work.

Abhinav